# npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: npm

*when i check node -v it's alright and prints out. But npm is shows this error. How can I fix this? Please help me. *

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I searched a lot of time and found solutions. 
once installed **nodejs -> Kindly restart the laptop** 
then set the **path (system properties -> environment settings -> C:\Program Files\nodejs)** 
now **open cmd and type -> C:\Users\solomon\Desktop\react-project>npm start**
it will work by opening browser with **http://localhost:3000**

**or**

if **npm not works in Visual studio code** 
open vs code then **Ctrl+P** -> type - **ext install npm script runner** 
you have to choose one and install it.
once installed **please close and open Visual studio code**
and go to vs code terminal and type **npm start** and browser will start **http://localhost:3000**
Wow its works great.

Comment: a simple reboot did the trick.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I solved it. Incase of next time**

Open the Control Panel (Click the Start button, then click Control Panel)

Click User Accounts

Click Change my environment variables

Select PATH and click the Edit... button
At the end of the Variable value, add;
C:\Program Files\nodejs

Click Ok on the "Edit User Variable" window, then click Ok on the "Environment Variables" window

Start a command prompt window (Start button, then type cmd into the search and hit enter)

At the prompt (C:>) type npm and hit enter; you should now see some help text (Usage: npm  etc.) rather than "npm is not recognized..."
Now you can start using npm!

Answer (score 1):

1. First close the **IDE**
2. Then open **Edit the system environment variables** and **click environment variables -> system variables.**
3. go to the **Path** and click **new**
4. Add the path as **C:\Program Files\nodejs**
5. Finally the error is fixed and run npm start

Answer (score 0):

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm install
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nvm for the usage of the different versions of node. As a fresh installation, I've installed node version X but didn't apply "use" command for this node version.

Command "nvm ls" should return an asterisk before the current node version.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar situation like run on windows shell throws error but run on other bash terminal gets running successfully

Answer (score 0):

make sure you've installed the node package manager
-> navigate to start menu
1- search for "Environment Variables".
2- navigate to "System Variable" Box.
3- Click on "PATH" -> "Edit"
4- Press New -> Browse
5- Add The Path of the node (Most Likely you'll find it in 'C:/ program files')

Answer (score 0):

I was very frustrated of this issue when I got this error while installing Tailwind CSS.
what you need to do is INSTALL Node.js for your platform.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and all I had to do was restart my computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).